# pushing and retrieving a html file stored on sdcard of an android emulator

Tags: android, sd-card

i would like to know how to do store and retrieve files from the sd card of an emulator from within an activity ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "pull and push files into the sdcard" over USB from an activity.

If that is not what you are asking, please consider editing your question and clarifying what you are seeking.

Comment: thanks , it's just i wanted to the equivalent of it..i.e store and retrieve files from the sdcard of an android emulator.